# How to extract values and compute based on other column in R (data.table)

Tags: r, data.table

Would like to calculate the value based on level within each group. Say, `(a - b) / c`, and then create a new column for the result.

```
library(data.table)
DT =data.table(Group=rep(LETTERS[1:3], each=3),
               level=rep(letters[1:3],3), 
               value=sample(100,9))[order(Group)]
#    Group level value
# 1:     A     a    78
# 2:     A     b    10
# 3:     A     c    94
# 4:     B     a    68
# 5:     B     b    76
# 6:     B     c    46
# 7:     C     a   100
# 8:     C     b    54
# 9:     C     c    55

DT[,Result:=(DT[level=="a", .(value), by=.(Group,level)]$value -
             DT[level=="b", .(value), by=.(Group,level)]$value) /
             DT[level=="c", .(value), by=.(Group,level)]$value]
#    Group level value     Result
# 1:     A     a    78  0.7234043
# 2:     A     b    10 -0.1739130
# 3:     A     c    94  0.8363636
# 4:     B     a    68  0.7234043
# 5:     B     b    76 -0.1739130
# 6:     B     c    46  0.8363636
# 7:     C     a   100  0.7234043
# 8:     C     b    54 -0.1739130
# 9:     C     c    55  0.8363636
```

Must be some graceful ways to do this in data.table.
Please advise, **Thanks**

Comment: I can match your output values by `DT[, (value[level=="a"] - value[level=="b"]) / value[level=="c"], by=Group]` but I don't really understand the logic of why you would assign the `Result` variable in that way.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I need it because I wanna do some more other things, like make note on ggplot, so I need the Result column. `DT[,Result:=DT[, (value[level=="a"] - value[level=="b"]) / value[level=="c"], by=Group]$V1]` **THANKS**

Comment: maybe tell us what you want or describe your problem rather than show us what you did? this might help `dcast(DT, Group ~ level)[, Result := (a - b) / c]`

Comment: @chinsoon12 Thanks. I wanna plot a bar chart with a, b, and note the result on it, since I prefer `%>%`, so it would be easier to prep the table before ggplot. Thanks for advice.